# How to validate django custom model field attributes?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am writing custom model field called `EnumField` for mysql database, which looks like below

```
class EnumField(models.Field):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.values = kwargs['values']
       kwargs['choices'] = [(key, value) for key, value in self.values]
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
       enum_values = ",".join([key for key, value in self.values])
       return f"ENUM({enum_values})"
```

I hope this works well, but i can't figure out way to enforce constraints such as the `values` attribute should be `list` or `tuple`., and values attribute should contain unique key and values.

for example if anyone tries to use `EnumField` like below with `duplicate values` or `isinstance(values)` is not `tuple or list`  i need to throw exception., How can i achieve that.

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    field1 = EnumField(values=(('Y', 'yes'), 'Y', 'Yes')) //Invalid &need to raise exception
    field2 = EnumField(values=(('Y', 'yes'), ('N', 'No'))) // valid
    field3 = EnumField(values="check") //invalid & need to raise exception
    field4 = EnumField(values=[1,2,3]) //Invalid & need to raise exception
    field5 = EnumField(values=[('LIVE', 'Live'), ('OFFLINE', 'Offline')]) //valid
```

Answer (score 0):

[Unique is what you want](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique)

[Here is the link to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-custom-model-fields)

If you don't want this to happen on Database level, you want python code like this

```py
if isinstance(var, tuple):
    do something
else:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Not a tuple")
```

Comment: i just want make sure `values` should be unique, not at the database level. and allow values should be `list` or `tuple` only

Comment: I am not sure this is possible

Comment: like when we use `CharField` it throws `max_length` exception